# ImageMagick - Merging pair of images (the same file name) with different extension in the folder

Tags: imagemagick

I have pair of images in the folder:

221013.bmp
221013.png
221018.bmp
221018.png
221020.bmp
221020.png

I'm trying to merge every pair of images in a folder and combine that result into a JPG file with imagemagick

`magick convert C:\Img\*.bmp -set filename:f "%t" "C:\Img\%[filename:f].png" -composite "C:\Img\%[filename:f].jpg"`

One JPG with correct name is created and error:
convert: unable to open image 'C:\Img%[filename:f].png': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3537.

Any idea?, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your system memory can hold all the BMP and PNG images, and if every BMP image has a PNG to match, a command like this will read in all the BMPs, set the output filenames, add an ImageMagick special image called "null:" to separate the two sets of images, then read in the PNGs. The "-layers composite" operation takes each image from before the "null:", composites it with its companion image from after the "null:", and outputs the results with the filenames of the input BMPs.

```
magick *.bmp -set filename:f "%[t]" null: *.png -layers composite "%[filename:f].jpg"
```

This requires you run the command in the folder containing the images.

Edited to add: Unless you need the behavior of ImageMagick v6, you should omit "convert" from the command and just use "magick" to get IMv7 behavior.

Answer (score 0):

First, type `convert -list configure`.

Check from the output if delegate libraries like `libjpeg`, `libbmp` and (in this case) `libpng` have been installed.

If that doesn't work, maybe change the names of the versions with different extensions and try something like [this](https://imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php) `mogrify -format jpg *.*` to convert them to the same format first? Don't forget the `-format` flag or your files may be overwritten. Back up just in case.