# Is there a way to compose a batch of images with imagemagick?

Tags: image-processing, cmd, imagemagick, png, composite

I have a series of PNG images (`ABC_a.png`, `ABC_b.png`, `XYZ_a.png`, `XYZ_b.png`, `BCA_a.png`, `BCA_b.png` etc.) and would like to compose every image of the same code (i.e. the name of an image without `_a` or `_b`) within a folder.

Manually, the code would look like this:

```
magick composite ABC_b.png ABC_a.png ABC.png
magick composite XYZ_b.png XYZ_a.png XYZ.png
magick composite BCA_b.png BCA_a.BCA BCA.png
...
```

... where a partly transparent image `_b` would be placed "on top of" `_a` and the name of the output file losing its `_a`/`_b` suffix.

I looked around and tried several apporaches via `mogrify` or for loops (`FOR %i IN (*.png) DO magick composite ...`) but couldn't get it automated. Perhaps it would help to use two separate folders and working with the same image names (without the suffix), but I'm not sure...

I appreciate any tips. Please be aware that I'd need to work within the Windows CMD or PowerShell to make it happen.

Comment: I don't use Windows, but in general it's simpler to iterate over `*_a.png` and then work out the name of the corresponding `*_b.png` file. I mean `FOR %i IN (*_a.png) DO ...`

Comment: I tried that too, but I have no idea how the correct expression for `DO ...` would actually look like

Comment: You should be able to do something similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74133845/imagemagick-merging-pair-of-images-the-same-file-name-with-different-extensi/74134390#74134390

Answer (score 2):

There can be used the following batch file for this task:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "ImageMagick=magick.exe"
if exist "*!*_a.png" goto ExtendedVersion

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%I in (*_a.png) do (
    set "FileNameA=%%~nI"
    set "FileName=!FileNameA:~0,-2!%%~xI"
    if not exist "!FileName!" "!ImageMagick!" composite "!FileNameA:~0,-1!b%%~xI" "!FileNameA!%%~xI" "!FileName!"
)
endlocal
goto EndBatch

:ExtendedVersion
echo INFO: Extended version required because of a PNG file with exclamation marks.
for %%I in (*_a.png) do (
    set "FileNameA=%%~nI"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "FileName=!FileNameA:~0,-2!%%~xI"
    if not exist "!FileName!" "!ImageMagick!" composite "!FileNameA:~0,-1!b%%~xI" "!FileNameA!%%~xI" "!FileName!"
    endlocal
)

:EndBatch
endlocal
```

There is defined first the required execution environment with the first two command lines.

Next the environment variable `ImageMagick` is defined with the file name of this program. It would be best to add the full path because in this case `cmd.exe` would not need to search for `magick.exe` in current directory and next in all directories in string value of environment variable `PATH` using the file extensions in string value of environment variable `PATHEXT` before each execution of *ImageMagick*. The usage of the fully qualified file name of *ImageMagick* would avoid hundreds or even thousands of file system accesses on more than ten PNG files to process.

The **IF** condition in the fourth command line quickly checks if there is any PNG file with case-insensitive `_a` in the file name before the file extension `.png` containing one or more exclamation marks in the file name. The extended version of the processing loop is required if this condition is true.

The standard version enables first required [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html). Then a **FOR** loop is used to process one PNG file after the other with case-insensitive `_a` in the file name before the file extension `.png`.

The current file name without file extension `.png` is assigned first to the environment variable `FileNameA`.

Next a string substitution is used to get from the string value of the environment variable `FileNameA` the file name without the last two characters `_a` concatenated with the file extension `.png` assigned to the environment variable `FileName`.

If there is not already a PNG file not ending with `_a` in the file name before the file extension, there is next executed *ImageMagick* with first argument being the corresponding `_b.png` file determined by using again a string substitution with using the file name string assigned to the environment variable `FileName` without last character `a` concatenated with `b` and the file extension `.png` and the`_a.png` file with the file extension as second argument and the file name without `_a` as third argument.

The command **ENDLOCAL** after the loop restores the previous environment before enabling delayed expansion and the command **GOTO** instructs the Windows Command Processor to continue processing the batch file with the command line below the label `EndBatch` which contains one more **ENDLOCAL** to restore the environment on starting the batch file processing.

The extended version is nearly the same as the standard version. The difference is that delayed variable expansion is not enabled on assigning the file name of the current `_a.png` file without the file extension to the environment variable `FileNameA`. That avoids interpreting the exclamation mark(s) in the file name as beginning/end of a delayed expanded variable reference resulting in a manipulation of the file name string before assigning it to the environment variable as it would happen with delayed expansion already enabled.

The extended version enables next delayed variable expansion inside the loop, does the same as the standard version and restores finally the previous environment before processing the next `_a.png` file.

The extended version is slower because of the environment variables list copy and the other operations made in background by every execution of **SETLOCAL** as explained in full details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67039507/3074564). The command **ENDLOCAL** in the loop is required to avoid a stack overflow on processing lots of PNG files.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`